# Transform property jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#space').css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'scale(2,3)',
        });
        $('#space').css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'skew(30deg,20deg)',
        });
      });

CSS
 #space{transition:duration:20s;}
```

Using the above Jquery, I want the scale property to run for the first 20 seconds and then the skew property for the next 20 seconds but here it only does skew.I was thinking to provide a delay of 20 seconds for the next statement but is there any other simple way to do it? Thanks

Comment: use delay() http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: That is because you're overriding the scale with skew.

Comment: @dreamweiver Thanks I have been trying the syntax but unable to figure it out. could you please kindly let me know the syntax of it. Thanks.
$('#space').css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'skew(30deg,20deg)',
            }).delay(2000);? right?

Comment: yes thats the syntax , you can refer the Jquery Site for more detailed info :) happy coding

Comment: You can't use delay on setting CSS properties. Only works for effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.delay()` for CSS properties. Instead, you can try using the `setInterval()` function to progressively add transform to your element based on a predefined set of transform you want. I have made a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5AqCm/

This answer is made under the assumption that you want to, eventually, both scale *and* skew the element in it's final state.

Let me explain my code a little:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $spce = $("#space"),
        trsfm = [],            // Declare empty array for transforms
        delay = 1000,          // Set delay in ms
        count = 0;             // Set iteration count

    // Declare a stepwise array where you want the transform to occur
    trsfm = ['scale(2,3)', 'skew(30deg,20deg)'];

    var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
        if(count < trsfm.length) {
            // Increase count by 1
            count += 1;

            // Stepwise addition of transforms
            var trsfmStep = trsfm.slice(0, count).join(' ');
            $spce.css({
                '-moz-transform': trsfmStep,
                '-o-transform': trsfmStep,
                '-webkit-transform': trsfmStep,
                'transform': trsfmStep
            });

            // Log in the console, just for fun
            console.log(trsfmStep);

        } else {
            // If you have iterated through all the transforms, clear interval
            window.clearInterval(timer);   
            console.log('Timer cleared.');
        }
    }, delay);
});
```

I have defined the delay, 1000ms (of course you can change that), and also used an array to store all the transforms you want to apply. The transforms are applied in a step-wise fashion from left to right, starting from scale and then to skew.

A timer is set, and the count is started. Every time an interval is reached, the script checks if you have iterated through the transform array. If not, it will apply stepwise addition of the transform, by joining the items in the array from the start, but stopping at whatever step you are at (using the `.slice()`) method :)

Comment: I am deleting my answer, I am not sure that delay will work on CSS.. Going by what you wrote..